# AVX or other's set instruction that can extract a specific bit, given an index from multiple integers in parrallel?

Tags: bit-manipulation, avx

Example: a=11010**0**01 , b=0001**0**01, c=11010**0**00, d = 11111**1**11

extract(a,b,c,d,2) == 0001

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are two cases: 1. The position of interest is a compile-time constant, and 2. 
The position of interest is not a compile-time constant. Both cases are answered
in the code below.

Note that if a, b, c, d, are consecutive in memory, then you can simply move them to an xmm
register by `x = _mm_load_si128((_m128i*) &d);`, which is much more efficient than
`_mm_set_epi32()` used here.

The code:

```c
/*  gcc -O3 -m64 -Wall -march=broadwell extract_2nd_bit.c  */
#include <immintrin.h>
#include <stdio.h>

/* If position i = 2 (for axample) is known at compile time: */
int extract_2nd_bit(int a, int b, int c, int d){
    __m128i x = _mm_set_epi32(a, b, c, d);
            x = _mm_slli_epi32(x, 31 - 2);       /* shift bit 2 to the highest position */
    return _mm_movemask_ps(_mm_castsi128_ps(x)); /* extract the MSB of the 4 elements   */
}

/* If position i is unknown at compile time: */
int extract_var(int a, int b, int c, int d, int i){
    __m128i x = _mm_set_epi32(a, b, c, d);
            x = _mm_sll_epi32(x, _mm_cvtsi32_si128(31 - i)); /* shift bit i to the highest position */
    return _mm_movemask_ps(_mm_castsi128_ps(x));             /* extract the MSB of the 4 elements   */
}


int print_32_bin(unsigned int x);

int main(){
    int a = 0b11010001; 
    int b = 0b0001001; 
    int c = 0b11010000; 
    int d = 0b11111111;
    int pos = 2;
    print_32_bin(extract_2nd_bit(a, b, c, d));
    print_32_bin(extract_var(a, b, c, d, pos));
    return 0;
}




int print_32_bin(unsigned int x){
    for (int i=31;i>=0;i--){
        printf("%1u",((x>>i)&1));
    }
    printf("\n");
    return 0;
}
```

The output is:

```
$ ./a.out
00000000000000000000000000000001
00000000000000000000000000000001
```

By the way, why didn't you set the `avx` or `sse` tag in the question?

Answer (score 1):

Try using the

unsigned __int64 _pext_u64 (unsigned __int64 a, unsigned __int64 mask)

command, though it doesn't use multiple integers.

There are other ways using ANDs and variable SHIFTs (and other commands).

Answer (score 1):

This algorithm is not optimal, because the filling of the 32-bit register is done serially. But you should get the gist. It is the [`PEXT instruction`](http://www.felixcloutier.com/x86/PEXT.html)  from the BMI2 instruction set that can do this efficiently.

This is a solution in MASM x86 assembly (a, b, c, d are BYTE values in memory):

```
mov ah, a
mov al, b
shl eax, 16
mov ah, c
mov al, d
; Now EAX = aaaaaaaabbbbbbbbccccccccdddddddd
mov ecx,  0b00000100000001000000010000000100    ; MASK value
pext eax, eax, ecx
; Now EAX = 00000000000000000000000000000001    ; result
```

For practical use, optimize the filling of the 32-bit source register (here: `EAX`).

Now the lowest 4 bits of `EAX` should contain `0001`.

Comment: Beware that PEXT is very slow on AMD CPUs that support it (like Zen).  Even on Intel, it's not clear that shift/AND + OR to do the whole job manually would be any more efficient than packing 4 integers into 1 to set up for `pext`, unless you could avoid some AND thanks to knowing they were already zero-extended.  Or maybe on Silvermont where writing AH simply merges, instead of Haswell/SKL where writing AH renames it, and reading EAX causes a 1-cycle merge stall where no other uops can be issued.